# flot chart actual data with percentage

Tags: jquery, charts

Im new to flot chart and javascript/jquery so I don't have much idea how stuff work. How do I show my label in a format like "data:percentage" style?

I got the percentage codes from SO:

```
pie: {
         show: true,
         label: {
             show: true,
             // Added custom formatter here...
             formatter: function(label,point){
                 return(point.percent.toFixed(2) + '%');
             }
         }
    }
```

And data codes from SO:

```
label: {
                show: true,
                radius: 2 / 3,
                formatter: function (label, series) {
                    return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;">' + label + '<br/>' + series.data[0][1] + '</div>';
                },
                threshold: 0.1
            }
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code?

Comment: I want to combine these two codes which show in a format of "data:%"...but I dont know how..

Comment: Do you know how to use `jsfiddle.net` this would be really helpful if you show what you're currently doing. Just write a short example of how you're using it.

Comment: im new to jsfiddle.net too...I post my code in http://jsfiddle.net/r4CmU/ , but i dont know how i add my js chart file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve the problem myself:

```
formatter: function (label, series) {
                            return "<div style='font-size:15pt;'>" + label + "<br>" + series.data[0][1] + " : " + series.percent.toFixed(2) + "%" + "</div>";
                        }
```